# TimePicker not showing bound property value

Tags: c++-winrt

TimePicker control is not showing the bound Time value

Properties :

```
String SystemTime() const 
{
    return m_systemTime;
}

void SystemTime(String value)
{
    __super::SetProperty(m_systemTime, value, L"SystemTime");
}
```

Formatter :

```
DateTimeFormatter TimeFormatter(L"hour minute", {L"en-US"}, L"US", CalendarIdentifiers::Gregorian(), ClockIdentifiers::TwentyFourHour());
```

Xaml Data binding :

```
<TimePicker x:Name="timePicker" x:Uid="timePicker" Grid.Row="1" ClockIdentifier="24HourClock" Time="{x:Bind MainViewModel.SystemTime, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Setting value :

```
SystemTime(TimeFormatter.Format(clock::now()));
```

It always selects 0:00. Am I missing something or there is a bug in WinRT time picker?[image]

Duration Since Mid-Night Getter :

```
std::chrono::system_clock::duration duration_since_midnight()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    time_t tnow = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    tm* date = std::localtime(&tnow);
    date->tm_hour = 0;
    date->tm_min = 0;
    date->tm_sec = 0;
    auto midnight = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(date));

    return now - midnight;
}
```

This gives the duration. And this duration can be used directly as TimeSpan for Selected Time.

Comment: The documentation for the [`Time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepicker.time) property contains the following remark: *"The value of `SelectedTime` **is used to populate the time picker** and is `null` by default. If `SelectedTime` is `null`, the `Time` property is set to a `TimeSpan` of 0"*. This sounds like you want to bind to the `SelectedTime` property instead. Either property refers to a `TimeSpan` so I doubt that you can pass a `String` (indeed, I don't know what `String` is here).

Comment: @IInspectable String is hstring. How can we get the current time as time TimeSpan?

Comment: [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.timespan) maps to [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) in C++/WinRT. Presumably, the `TimePicker` control expects the time interval since midnight. Unless there is a function in any of the libraries you use to produce this value you would have to implement your own `duration_since_midnight` function.